# Absolute positioned div needs bottom margin on document with fixed footer

Tags: html, css

Somehow I can't figure out what I'm missing...

I try to position a number of `absolute` divs between two `fixed` bars (header and footer). Header contains some tabs and footer contains an copyright. I want to use the window's scrollbar and not an overflowed div and I know it should be possible!

Every absolute positioned div should carry an extra margin, so that the bottom of that div does not disappear behind the footer.

[image]

It should become something like this:
[image]

A snippet of my problem is available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LnEv2/) on jsfiddle.

My HTML:

```
<ul class="cf tabs">
    <li>Tab 1</li>
    <li>Tab 2</li>
</ul>
<div style="margin-top: 40px; padding-bottom: 30px; position:relative">
    <div style="position:absolute;top:300px; height:100px; width: 250px; left:200px; border: 1px solid purple;">aaa</div>

    <div style="position:absolute;top:0px; height:100px; width: 100px; left:100px; border: 1px solid purple;">bbb</div>

    <div style="position:absolute;top:450px; height:100px; width: 250px; left:400px; border: 1px solid purple;">ccc</div>
</div>
<div class="cf footer">Copyright &copy;</div>​
```

The stylesheet I'm using:

```
    ul.tabs {
        list-style-type: none;
        list-style-position: outside;
        padding:5px;
        margin: 0;
        position:fixed;
        top:0;
        z-index: 999;
        background-color: white;
        left:0;
        right:0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid green;
        opacity: 0.7;
    }
    ul.tabs li {
        float: left;
        margin:1px;
        padding: 4px 10px 2px 10px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }


    div.footer {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right:0;
        background-color:#DEDEE9;
        border-top: 3px outset #BBBBBB;
        padding: 5px;
        opacity: 0.6;
    }

    .cf:before,
    .cf:after {
        content: " "; 
        display: table; 
    }
    .cf:after {
        clear: both;
    }​
```

Do you guys have any hints?

**Extra info**
As you can see in the attached image the purple border of squared div at bottom right is overlapping the fixed footer. I do not want this. There should be given a bottom margin somewhere, so that every div carries an extra margin so it should match the top of the footer

Comment: I don't really understand your question. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Not clear what exactly you need to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the solution I've come up with. Wrap the bottommost absolutely positioned `div` inside with another `div`, on which put bottom margin equal to footer height and the border. I gave it class `.inner`.

See my [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LnEv2/24/).

Comment: Yeah, this seems like a pretty nice workaround... Let me play with it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Add bottom padding to the document `body` equivalent to the height of the footer:

```
body {
     padding-bottom: 31px;
}
```

(JSFiddle doesn't seem to let you modify styling of the `body` element, so I can't post a fiddle. It should work, though.)

Comment: Try it on the `html` element instead. Or try `margin` instead of `padding`.

Comment: Sorry, not working on `html` element either. Tried `margin` as well as `padding`

Answer (score -3):

Instead of using absolute positioning, do something like:

margin - left : 800px

Margin - top: 500px

Comment: At what element? If I have multiple elements they are not floating at the specified positions, but 'stacked'

Comment: I'm not a pro or anything, but I've always had issues with absolute positioning, so I just starting declaring my divs by the left and top margin and positioning them like that.

Comment: Try putting two divs next to each other, you cannot do this easily without position `absolute`